# Can "Please create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example" be an Auto-Comment

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, minimal-reproducible-example

When I vote to close a question because it is a duplicate, a comment is automatically inserted:

> possible duplicate of...

Could we add an automatic comment when I vote to close because it lacks, "the shortest code necessary to reproduce:"

> Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This question deserves an answer. The duplicate just discusses the introducing of `[mcve]` link, while this questions asks for the mcve link to be automatically added to a flagged question. Do we have such a flag? if so, which one is it?

Comment: @OfirD In a way yes. The appropriate flag (if you can't vote to close) is `needs improvement`->`A community-specific reason`->`Needs debugging details` including the text "...the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." When the question is closed, there's a link above to [What does it mean if a question is "closed"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and from there a link to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which contains a section about "Questions *seeking debugging help*" and a link to the MCVE help page.

Comment: ...which is now [mre], "MRE", not MCVE.

Comment: @HereticMonkey for historic reasons those still works, even [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=reprex) is still a hit in the search ...

Comment: @JeanneDark Having to find the correct link twice on pages containing dozens of links isn't exactly the same as being linked directly to the target, is it? FWIW, even after reading your comment I *still* had to actively look for the correct links.

Comment: I second @MisterMiyagi. What's more, Jeanne Dark's suggestion only instructs an OP *after* their question is closed. Having a flag that behaves like the duplicate flag, so that it would add an informative comment with the MRE link, is much more constructive.

Comment: If people want to do this, should it not be expanded to all the other close reasons too?